# Regular expression to blacklist a set of words

Tags: php, regex, api

I am trying to use an api provided by another website. There is a method `searchReports` to which I can pass a word or a regular expression(php). I want to pass a regular expression for matching anything other than these words. `China,Russia,North Korea` . I tried some but nothing worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^(?!(country1|country2|country3)$).*$` finally worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one:

```
/^((?!(^china$)|(^russia$)|(^north korea$)).)*$/i
```

The "i" at the end stands for "ignore-case". Does php deal ok with it?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
/^(?:(?!blacklisted|set|ofwords).)*\z/
```

Comment: It should match only the word not substrings.  For example Shanghai china should not be blacklisted.

Comment: The answer can become more valuable if you are adding some explanation and links to documentation, so the original poster and other users can actually learn from it.